# Upgrade Terraform from v12 to v13 hitting errors

Tags: terraform, upgrade

Hoping someone can help - I am trying to upgrade terraform from V12 to v13 I have used the upgrade command and currently have terraform 13.7 on my machine - But I am getting this error
"Error: Unsupported Terraform Core version
This configuration does not support Terraform version 0.12.20. To proceed,
either choose another supported Terraform version or update the root module's
version constraint." Can anyone help?

Comment: My first guess would be a provider block needs to be updated as well. Can you add what your provider blocks look like to the post?

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 0):

Check your [version constraints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/version-constraints.html) within your Terraform configuration block.

There will be a field where the version is set to 0.12.20.

It's also possible that you're consuming a module that has that hardcoded (which is not a good practice).